# How to flatten a list with tibbles and tibbles within lists to have all tibbles on the same level?

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a list where the list elements are tibbles or lists that contain multiple tibbles. I would like to get a list where all the tibbles are on the same level.

How would I do that?

```
library(tibble)

tib_1 <- tibble(a = 1:4, b = LETTERS[1:4])
tib_2 <- tibble(c = 1:4, d = LETTERS[1:4])
tib_3 <- tibble(e = 1:4, f = LETTERS[1:4])
tib_4 <- tibble(g = 1:4, h = LETTERS[1:4])

my_list <- list(tib_1, tib_2, list(tib_3, tib_4))

desired_list <- list(tib_1, tib_2, tib_3, tib_4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `flatten`

```
library(rlang)
out <- flatten(my_list)
```

-checking

```
identical(desired_list, out)
#[1] TRUE
```